# Making calculations on Multi Dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a flot chart using values from MySQL database. SO i did

```
//creating array of pairs of x and y values

$dataArray = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) { //or whatever
    $dataArray[] = array( $row['xvalue'], $row['yvalue'] );
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //puting array in javascript
    var dataArray = <?php echo json_encode($dataArray); ?>;

    //ploting the graph
    $(function () {
         $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ dataArray ]);
    });
</script>
```

Everything works fine
But now the problem is in modifying the values(contents) of "$dataArray" .
I want to modify all the yvalues while xvalue remains same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php). IN this example i create an array with x/y values and calculate add 1000 to the y value:

```
<?php
$a[]=array(10,20);
$a[]=array(10,30);

function calc(&$v,$k){
if($k==1){
    $v = $v+1000;  //Calculate
    }
}

$b=array_walk_recursive($a, "calc");
print_r($a);

?>
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 1020
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 1030
        )

)
```

Comment: WOrked Perfectly,
Thankuuu :)

Comment: I wan't to know one more thing, 
How can I pass a variable to the function `calc(&$v,$k)` .

Comment: thanks :) - you can add a third parameter to calc, like this: calc(&$v,$k,$x) and then in you can pass for example 555 like this: $b=array_walk_recursive($a, "calc",555);

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($Array as &$Values)
{
    $Values[1] = YOUROPERATIONS;
}
```

Comment: When you say

`foreach($Array as &$Values)`

How can you imagine that which value will be taken as $Value (xvalue or Yvalue). Surely

`$dataArray[] = array( $row['xvalue'], $row['yvalue'] );`

is not as

`$Array = ($row['xvalue'] => $row['yvalue']);`
//or
`$Array[$xvalue] = $yvalue;`

Comment: The result of `$Value` will be array, not a single value (foreach is not resursive)... And he didn't make an associative array, so it has numericas keys. Do you even know how arrays in PHP works?

Comment: No, Actually I guess you know much more and that's why your code didn't worked at all.

Comment: `$DataArray[] = array(1, 2);
$DataArray[] = array(10, 15);

foreach($DataArray as &$Values)
{
    $Values[1] = $Values[1] * 2;
}`

Works perfectly fine (the `y` values are 4 and 30 after the `foreach` loop)...